# The EntitySet name 'AtlanticBioContext.CompanyCustomers' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I am working on a project tied to a SQL 2000 server which the client cannot change at this time.  With edmgen2.exe I was able to create a edmx file for VS2010.  However, when I attempt to make the following call:

```
CompanyCustomer customer = ctx.CompanyCustomers.Where(o => o.Company_id == "77151").Single     <CompanyCustomer>();
```

I get the following exception: The EntitySet name 'AtlanticBioContext.CompanyCustomers' could not be found.  I have checked the edmx file and it looks like the EntitySet is defined there:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="AtlanticBio" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="AtlanticBioContext">
      <EntitySet Name="CompanyCustomers" EntityType="AtlanticBio.CompanyCustomer" />
      <EntitySet Name="CUSTOMER" EntityType="AtlanticBio.Customer" />
      <EntitySet Name="Products" EntityType="AtlanticBio.Products" />
```

I have googled the error above to attempt to get an idea of how EF defines the set above, but I have not been able to find much.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that EF4 doesn't support SQL Server 2000.

Comment: My research shows that EF4 does support SQL 2000, but VS2010 editor does not.  Which is why I needed to create files( csdl, msl, ssdl ) via edmgen.exe.  However, I found edmgen2.exe which would go a step further and generate an edmx file.  This worked as I can see editor and classes in VS2010, however I'm running into issues.

Comment: If you for example use `Take` and `Skip` in query does it work? The problem is that EF can generate incompatible SQL at runtime.